# Does hadoop sequence file adds dummy data to it

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sequencefile

In my case i am trying to incorporate all the given image files to a hadoop sequence file to avoid the small files problem. Hence i first created the sequence file with the help  of a mapper application. The key of each image file is the path to it and the corresponding value will be the byte array of the image file. While writing the image to the sequence file the size of the byte array of image is let's say 14k. Whenever i try to read the value from a sequence file(output of first mapper) with the help of another mapper the size of the read byte array drastically increases to let's say 500k. Don't know where the problem is. Please help me out with this.

Comment: You could create a sequence file with one image in it and check the size perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I did tried it with a single image. It actually appends 0s at the end of original data.